# Vertically Align multi-line text inside a div with multiple spans

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and css code snippets

```
<div class="table">
 <div class="table-cell">
  <span class="span"> A </span>
  <span class="span"> B </span>
  <span class="span"> C <br> D something something something </br> </span>  
 </div>
</div>

.table {
 display: table;
 width: 50%;
}

.table-cell {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 20%;
}

.span {
 float: left;
}
```

that output

```
ABC 
  D something something something`
```

Now if I add another `something` to the second line, the output will be:

```
AB 
C 
D something something something something
```

while my expected output is:

```
ABC 
  D something something something
  something
```

which means that I don't want `C` to be moved to another line when content reaches width limit. Does anyone know how I can achieve that (it's obvious that I don't want to increase the width)?

Here is the code if you'd like to play with it: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lhqqcfs4/

Comment: Your fiddle already showcases C not being moved to another line as your expected output shows. You're only experiencing the unexpected output above on large widths, which is due to the `width` being percentage-driven, and word-wrap.

Comment: @ObsidianAge My fiddle is without the fourth `soemthing`, if you add that `C` moves.

Comment: float: bottom does not exist. Maybe you mean vertical-align: bottom

Comment: @media Not at large widths. It only happens narrowly because you're using a table and word-wrap. Do you want the text to escape the bounds of your table?

Comment: @itacode I removed that. That doesn't make any difference in the scenario.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I don't want to escape the bounds of the table and my expected output doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following way, hope it helps:

```css
.table {
 display: table;
 width: 50%;
}

.table-cell {
 display: table-cell;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 20%;
}

.span {
 float: left;
}
.col01 {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="table-cell">
  <span class="span"> A </span>
  <span class="span"> B </span>
  <span class="col01"> C <br> D something something something <br/> </span>  
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you inputting this table information dynamically? (i.e why not just add another `<br>` where you want the content to move to the next line?)

Alternatively, try giving the spans a set width; this would force the text to the next line.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhqqcfs4/1/

Comment: Yes, it's dynamic. So, that's not an option.